# Running SQL query on R for rows with NA

Tags: r, for-loop, na, sqldf

I'm trying to run a sql query in R using SQLDF but it keeps returning the error :  Error in rsqlite_send_query(conn@ptr, statement) : no such column: NA.

The query looks like this:

> sqldf("select ID, PhoneNO, type from sdi_update_2 where type = NA limit 20")

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`NA` isn't a thing in SQL, but `NULL` is - and `sqldf` converts R's `NA`s to SQL `null`s. Try:

```
sqldf("select ID, PhoneNO, type from sdi_update_2 where type is NULL limit 20")
```

Demo:

```
library(sqldf)
x = data.frame(a = c(1, NA))
sqldf("select * from x where a is NULL")
#    a
# 1 NA
```